# await request promise not working in safari 14, unhandled exception fires up

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise, safari, request

I have a small webapp that loads local html files into a div and it works wonders in chrome (with the allow-file-access-from-file param). This is just a local test thing so I'm not really worried about the CORS security issue for now.

The code is as follows:

```
await request({url: "test.html"})
    .then(data => { 
        document.getElementById("targetDiv").innerHTML = data.toString()
    });
```

In chrome it goes alright, but safari gives me an Unhandled Promise Rejection, with no further explanation.

EDIT: MY BAD, here's the request funcion:

```
function request (obj) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open(obj.method || "GET", obj.url);
        if (obj.headers) {
            Object.keys(obj.headers).forEach(key => {
                xhr.setRequestHeader(key, obj.headers[key]);
            });
        }
        xhr.onload = () => {
            if (xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 300) {
                resolve(xhr.response);
            } else {
                reject(xhr.statusText);
            }
        };
        xhr.onerror = () => reject(xhr.statusText);
        xhr.send(obj.body);
    });
}
```

I'm a beginner in js. This request function wasn't developed by me.

Comment: Does the Network tab show that the request is getting a response?

Comment: `request()` is not a standard browser function. Are you loading this from a library?

Comment: have you considered a try/catch - you may be able to get more information if you handle the rejection with an appropriate console or other output

Comment: Or call `.catch()`

Comment: @Barmar - I was suggesting something that didn't involve even more mixing of async/await with .then/.catch :D

Comment: `with the allow-file-access-from-file param` ... does safari 14 have a similar option? Easiest fix is to NOT use `file:///` protocol **at all** - because that is what causes the unhandled rejection (best guess)

Comment: I just updated the question with the request function. Sorry about that!!

Comment: `This request function wasn't developed by me` use `fetch` instead, then you don't have to fuss with new promsie and all that guff with XMLHttpRequest - this won't fix your issue, because your issue is you aren't using `http/s` for your **web** app

Comment: Got a solution that worked: `async function getPage(item) {
 return await fetch(item).then((response)=>response.text()).then((responsePage)=>{return responsePage});
}

async function injectIntoDiv(item, target) {
 let bodyText = await getPage(item);
 document.getElementById(target).innerHTML = bodyText;
}
`

Comment: Don't post a solution in comments. Post it as a proper answer.